# Extract the Docker command from VisualStudio's Docker integration

Tags: .net, visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I've created a running docker image of my *.Net Core API* with the Visual Studio Docker integration. But when I run my Dockerfile from the terminal without any specific arguments, the image is not working. Is there a way to extract the docker commands which Visual Studio executes internally? The launchSettings.json has a profile for docker, but doesn't include the docker command. Also the docker commands

```
docker inspect <image>
```

```
docker history <image>
```

did not help me solving this issue.

Eventually I want to run the docker image without VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the commands that are run by VS in the Output window pane (Ctrl+Alt+O) and switching the "Show output from" dropdown to "Container Tools". But these commands are unlikely to be the same commands that you'd run outside the context of VS because these commands are highly tuned for managing the debugging of your app. So the commands do things like volume mounting to configure remote debugging and provide access to the local NuGet package cache for performance purposes.

You can find documentation on how to build and run sample .NET Core projects for the official .NET Core Docker images at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples.

Also be sure to read up on the Docker build context if you're not familiar with it: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/. That's an important concept to understand because the location of your Dockerfile in relation to your project(s) matters. This is also discussed at the .NET GitHub page: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples/complexapp#building-an-image-including-multiple-projects.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your individual docker images don't have dependencies on other docker images yous should be able to run each docker image using individual `Dockerfile`.

Visual Studio has two options for generating docker images.

1. Right Click > Project > Add > Docker Support
2. Right Click > Project > Add > Container Orchestrator Support

Option #2 will add docker-compose. At the solution level.
You should be able to use `docker-compose` cli and should be able to work without visual studio support.

Visual studio 16.5.4 update only adds capabilities for the improved debugging experience. But that doesn't mean that you need special commands to work with `Dockerfile` or `Docker-compose`.

Another reason for this claim is .NET Core is cross-platform. .NET Core solutions could be created on a windows machine checked-in to source control. Checked out on a Linux/Mac machine and developed on Linux/Mac machine. Special VS commands will get in the way of cross-platform dev experience.

Please verify your error message. It should work.